# How to update video driver when I'm receiving error code 31?

Tags: windows-8, drivers, graphics-card

I am using a Dell Latitude 3540 with an AMD Radeon HD 8850M running Windows 8, recently the motherboard was replaced because the GPU was dying, after it was replaced it worked for a while, then I tried updating the driver, which failed, then it wouldn't detect the driver at all, after that I tried installing the old driver which also failed. I should mention that everything that was set to run with the AMD GPU still runs fine with it, as if the driver was there and intact.

The error I was getting when attempting to install the driver through the Device Manager was:

> This device is not working properly because Windows cannot load the drivers required for this device. (Code 31)

When I used the Catalyst install manager I got some generic "could not install driver".

Now I uninstalled the driver from the Device Manager and it shows the following:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/RC1n2Tv.jpg]

I tried using SlimWare Utilities SlimDrivers, but it just downloaded AMD's installer which proceeded to fail to install the driver. IOBit Driver Booster apparently succeeded in installing the driver, but it won't show up as installed in the Device Manager and the GPU is still not detected by AMD's Catalyst Control Center.

I'd appreciate it if anyone could help me solve this.

Comment: I am not sure whether it works for you or not. There are some software available to update drivers in our system like IOBit Driver Booster or SlimWare Utilities SlimDrivers. Try any of these(I prefer the first one). Just install it and it performs an automatic scan. After the scan, it will list new version for available drivers in your system. If you see any update for the drive you looking, just download and update it. This may solve the problem. Pleas let me know your experience.

Comment: which driver do you use? The ones from Dell or directly from AMD?

Comment: I am using drivers from Dell's site for Windows 8, I forgot to mention I tried to update to the 8.1 Driver without noticing it was not for 8.
I will try using IOBit Driver Booster, and report my results.
Thanks for editing the image in, magicandre1981

Comment: Have you tried to update to 8.1?  There a reason you decided to stay with 8.0?

Comment: I'm a bit scared of not having enough time to reinstall everything if I update to 8.1, but I'll probably be doing that sometime today, since I've run out of options.

Comment: Looks like updating to 8.1 did the trick, now games run badly, lol.